# Extract cli_test from "refs/heads/cli_test"

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using generic webhook in jenkins, and my webhook need to have only commit based. The webhook sent json has "refs/heads/cli_test" . I wanted to extract only the branch name i.e cli_test in jenkins using groovy script

Answer (score 0):

We can use minus function to remove unwanted contents in a string.
Eg;

```
BRANCH = "refs/heads/cli_test"
String branch = BRANCH.minus("refs/heads/")
```